# Generic implementation of IXmlSerializable

Tags: c#, xml, generics, serialization

I have a class, user defined, that almost all the objects in my code extend.  I want to implement iXmlSerializeable on this class so that I can control, at a base level, the way my object is serialized.  Specifically, I need the DateTime strings in the object to be treated in a specific way.  Yes, there are probably better ways to trick the application into stripping the TimeZone information from a serialized DateTime.  My Requirements however force me to ignore this face.  I need a way to write this into essentially a single function that wont have to affect or alter the code anywhere else in the application in order to achieve this effect.

Here is the implementation so far (reader Only, havent even started the writer yet):

```
    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        //loop through properties, Read property by name, converting as necessary based on property type.
        Type curType = this.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] pis;
        PropertyInfo prop = null;
        List<PropertyInfo> piList = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        //get all fields and properties (this does not need to be recursive, properties of the underlying object DO appear at this stage, unlike fields.
        pis = curType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pis)
            piList.Add(pi);

        bool isEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;

        reader.ReadStartElement();

        if (!isEmpty)
        {
            bool isProp = false;

            while (reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                if (!reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    if (piList.Select(a => a.Name).Contains(reader.Name))
                        isProp = true;

                    if (!isProp)//property not found?
                    {
                        reader.Skip();//cant do anything with it...keep going.
                        continue;
                    }

                    #region property set
                    prop = piList.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(reader.Name)).Single();
                    if (prop.CanWrite)
                    {
                        if (prop.PropertyType.BaseType.IsGenericType)
                        {//this should be one of the Rig Collections, are there any false positives?
                            ReadXmlCollection(prop, reader);
                        }
                        else if (prop.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BusinessObjectBase)))
                        {
                            //have to create a 'new' object, then call its reader to fill it in, then set the property value.
                            object newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, false);
                            prop.PropertyType.GetMethod("ReadXml").Invoke(newObj, new object[] { reader });
                            prop.SetValue(this, newObj, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string elVal = reader.ReadString();
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(elVal))
                            {
                                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                                    prop.SetValue(this, elVal, null);
                                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
                                    prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ToInt32(elVal), null);
                                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(double) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(double?))
                                    prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ToDouble(elVal), null);
                                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
                                    prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ToBoolean(elVal), null);
                                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                                {//special handle
                                    elVal = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(elVal, @"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.?\d*)([\+|-]\d{2}:\d{2})", "$1 $2");
                                    prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ToDateTime(elVal), null);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                }

                if (prop == null)//read anyway, something weird has happened?
                {
                    if (!reader.Read())
                        break;
                }
                else if(prop.Name.Equals(reader.Name))//only read if we are still on this node, otherwise, this has already been done.
                    if (!reader.Read())
                        break;

                prop = null;
                isProp = false;
            }
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    private void ReadXmlCollection(PropertyInfo prop, System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        string colName = reader.Name;
        object collectionIntance = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, false);
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        //now we are at the first element in the collection...what is it?
        Type ColType = prop.PropertyType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        while (reader.Name != colName && reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            object colObj = Activator.CreateInstance(ColType, false);
            ColType.GetMethod("ReadXml").Invoke(colObj, new object[] { reader });
            prop.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add", new Type[] {ColType}).Invoke(collectionIntance, new object[] { colObj });
        }
        prop.SetValue(this, collectionIntance, null);
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
```

I think it works...but its also slow as hell.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I also wouldn't mind a general idea of "Good Lord that's insane and will never work"...or something similar.  Keeping in mind, this is being implemented on an abstract base class, its running on already extended types.

Here's an extremely truncated and massively simplified example of the style of data I need to read:

```
<RigX>
    <isDirty>True</isDirty>
    <RXJob>
        <prop1>1.3</prop1>
        <prop2>False<prop2>
        <prop3>1984-08-10T09:30:00-06:00</prop3>
        <prop4 />
        <prop5>Hello World</prop5>
    </RXJob>
    <RXCollection>
        <ColObject>
            <p1>Yo</p1>
            <p2>Yellow</p2>
        </ColObject>
        <ColObject>
            <p1>No</p1>
            <p2>Orange</p2>
        </ColObject>
    </RXCollection>
    <RXNestedCollection>
        <RXNestedObject>
            <RXAnotherCollection>
                <RXAnotherObject>
                    <p1>1.9</p1>
                </RXAnotherObject>
            </RXAnotherCollection>
            <RXObject>
                <prop1>nope</prop1>
                <prop2>Im On A Horse!</prop2>
            </RXObject>
        </RXNestedObject>
    </RXNestedCollection>
</RigX>
```

In this example, RigX is the outer, single, object.  IsDirty is a property of RigX.  Likewise, RXJob, RXCollection, and RXNestedCollection are properties of RigX.  RXJob is an object, and the other two are collections.  RXCollection is a collection which contains an unknown number of user defined objects each of which is a simple object containing only primatives. RXNestedCollection contains an unknown number of user defined objects each of which contains other user defined objects and collections.

Comment: Can you post some example XML which you want to read using that code?

Comment: If you're going to do that for a large number of classes, then you should consider some form of code generation instead of using Reflection. In effect, use Reflection "at compile time" to generate the code you'll use at runtime, instead of using Reflection at runtime. That's basically what the XML Serializer does.

Comment: @John: There would be an answer I am looking for.  How would one go about writing this using "Code Generation"?  Simple examples are fine, I just need a lead on what to look for and the types of structures and implementations to use.

Comment: There are many options. One that I like, that is integrated with Visual Studio, is [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). It's a feature that can be used simply, or which can be used in a more sophisticated manner. It's a tool worth having in your belt. I had to create a SQL query that would have needed about 500 characters per column, for 27 columns, each column identical except for the name. Threw together a template, drove off the list of names, and there it was.

Comment: That would be extremely useful if I were writing one of these customized to each class in the application, I chose to go the generics route and try to write it in the Base class, useable by all the classes.